# SqlException timeout on GetConnection, but only from one node in a cluster

Tags: asp.net, timeout, cluster-computing, sqlexception

We have two nodes in a cluster. Both run an ASP.NET web application that connects to a database on another server. Node1 has no problems, but Node2 throws SqlExceptions, stating there's a timeout. The stacktrace shows me it's on `DbConnectionPool.GetConnection`.

I checked the versions of our DLLs, the web.config files, the connection strings, the MSDTC configuration on the nodes. All are identical.

Any ideas what could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the problem was hardware-related. Our client found a router with a hardware defect. After replacing that, all went well again.